# Internet sharing calendar permission issues exchange 2010 server

Tags: iis, exchange-2010, permissions

We have in our organization exchange server 2010 and we recently introduced calendar internet sharing option by following those instructions (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351201.aspx) to setup sharing policy. Everything was working fine until week ago. We did not touch anything on server side, and suddenly even if somebody share calendar and send link, nobody can access it. But it can in the outlook, so if go into outlook and click on "Sharing permissions" there is Anonymous as reviewer,  but when I go into webmail through browser, in sharing permissions I don't see anonymous (which is for everyone to see your published calendar). So after that when I use link that outlook created for me to share calendar, I paste it into browser URL and I get:

```
Server Error

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

There should not be any credentials to see this calendar, it is set to anonymous. And as I said it was working fine until about a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In a link that I was using, I just copied from outlook which was "http://webmail.yourdoman.com" instead I used "https://webmail.yourdoman.com" and it all worked.